# Can't create DotNetNuke module in VS2010, template issue?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I've been following the tutorial videos for DotNetNuke and i am at the part where i am now creating my own modules. I've installed everything i need to and put the template in the required folder, but whenever i try to create a project it comess up saying

```
"The local IIS URL http://dnndev/desktopmodules/... specified for Web project ... has not been configured"
```

It then asks me to create a virtual directory but says i cant because the server "http://dnndev" is not on the local machine.

I've searched for answers for a while now and have tried editing the template file and the host file but no matter what i try i always get the same message back. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow these steps for setting up your Development environment than the templates should work as is.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/development-environment.aspx

If you are using a different path for your website I would recommend customizing the templates.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Customize-Project-Template.aspx

Comment: Hi, sorry its taken me so long to get back to this. I've looked at editing the template before but for some reason it didn't work. My website is a localhost site located at http://localhost/dnn/. So I tried changing the following line in the template file <CustomParameter Name="$DevEnvironment$" Value="localhost/dnn" /> but it doesn't seem to have worked. Have i missed something else I need to change?

Comment: That is the correct line to change, though you need to modify that line, then repackage the template and recreate the project. Is it safe to assume you did all that?

Comment: Is repackaging where you re-zip the file up again after making the changes? If so yeah I've done that

Comment: I found that I actually missed a couple of lines in the CSProj file, check that file for references to DNNDEV and replace those with localhost/dnn if that is the path you are using. I think that will help

Comment: I just posted a new template that I believe resolves this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using [dotnetnuke wiki page link](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/creating-module-project.aspx) which seems confusing. For better steps go to: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/BlogID/16.aspx and locate "Let's Build a Module #1 - Project Introduction" which is a first video in step by step series of videos which will help you to clearly understand the process.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, I've visited the blog in your link and found the post you referred to but I can't find the video you mentioned. Are these the same videos that are on the training part of the DotNetNuke site? I've been going through them but they didn't encounter the issue I was having, probably due to how their machine and site are set up